# Consolidated deployment from one branch for a microservices architecture

Tags: github, deployment, microservices

Me and my team are building a product for a client in the microservices architecture. Generally for a startup product I always advise the founder to build monolithic and then as and when you scale convert it to microservices. But the founder is insisting on microservices. When i showed him the potential cost for splitting into true microservices, he came back and asked me to find a balance. So my question is surrounding this.

I am going to get my team to work on the microservices separately and build separate codebases. However I want to push the code to GITHUB in a consolidated folder and deploy that consolidated folder to cloud.

Is this a possible scenario. ? How can this be achieved.? What are the steps to take and what tools to use to achieve this. Please help.

I have tried creating a deployment folder and moved all the microservices below it as a sub branches. But on deploy to vercel(for testing) it is not coming together.